# Get instance public ip with chef recepie

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, cookbook

I try to get ip address of the instance and create my cron job:

```
command "curl --silent \"http://#{instance['public_ip']}/module.php/cron/cron.php?key=TPUmg16HBBZ8G2LgyySulHHuC2fGdIjf&tag=hourly\" > /dev/null 2>&1"
```

But when the instance lanched and when i list the cron job i found that {instance['public_ip']}= wrong ip address.
Can some one help me ? is this the right why to get the ip @

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the machine has multiple IPs, Chef can sometimes return the IP we aren't expecting.  In order to find the IP required, Chef support suggested overriding Ohai and that ended up working for us.

Create an attribute to regex match the IP expected:

`default['ohai']['override']['ip_matcher'] = '/^10\.\d+\.\d+\.4\d+/'`

Then we have to literally override Ohai by writing a file named with a Z, so it saves the IP address we want last.

```
# dynamically grab the path name
ohai_path = ::File.join(Ohai.config[:plugin_path][0], '/windows')

template "#{ohai_path}/zeta.rb" do
  # keep this template named zeta so it runs last.
  source 'zeta.rb.erb'
  variables(
    ip_matcher: node['ohai']['override']['ip_matcher']
  )
end
```

The template file looks like this (and was provided by Chef support):

```
Ohai.plugin(:Zeta) do
  provides 'ipaddress'
  depends 'ipaddress', 'network/interfaces'

  collect_data do
    network['interfaces'].each do | interf |
      network['interfaces']["#{interf[0]}"]['addresses'].each do | ip |
        if ip[0] =~ <%= @ip_matcher %>
          ipaddress ip[0]
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

usually, when chef-client is being executed within and ec2 instance, [ohai](https://docs.chef.io/ohai.html) will collect the [ec2 instance metadata](https://github.com/chef/ohai/blob/master/lib/ohai/plugins/ec2.rb) so you can get the public ip address of your instance by accessing the auto attributes:

```
node['ec2']['public_ipv4']
```